# c# replace custom tags

Tags: c#, regex, tags, string-formatting

I have a text editor similar to what is used on stack overflow. I am processing the text string in c# but also allowing users to format text within that using a custom tag. For example..

```
<year /> will output the current year.
"Hello <year /> World" would render Hello 2012 World
```

What I would like to do is to create a regular expression to search the string for any occurance of `<year />` and replace it. Further to that, I would also like to add attributes to the tag and be able to extract them so `<year offset="2" format="5" />`. I'm not great with RegEx but hopefully someone out there knows how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Is your file *actually* XML? That would make it a lot easier...

Comment: You need to escape the characters, your markup didn't come through.

Comment: Just because regex happens to be part of the solution *this time round* does not mean it should be part of the question. Regex is BAD BAD BAD BAD. **PLEASE** stop thinking that regex is a solution, "it never is - except in the cases where it the only solution". Next time please ask the question in a more general fashion - and possibly say that you couldn't use `XmlReader` etc. You should generally be more afraid of regex than a robber pointing a loaded gun at your head. Ok?

Comment: Thanks Johnathan. I assumed it would be the only solution in town to do what I wanted. I think I should have asked what is the best way to go about formatting text with the view to passing in attributes and extracting the values. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Regex will get you going, but ultimately my answer does have some funny borderline cases (what happens if you use `<year><foo /></year>`?); and hand-written parser/replacer will be more robust, reliable and predictable.

Comment: It's only going to be <year /> there won't be any twin tags involved, just trying to get my head around your code here :p

Comment: If you want [The Regulator](http://osherove.com/tools) can explain how a regex expression works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you shouldn't be using regex for this; but seeing as Html Agility Pack doesn't have a `HtmlReader` I guess you have to.

That being said, looking at other markup solutions, they often use a list of regex patterns and the relevant replacement - so we shouldn't write a 'general' case (e.g. `<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)>.*?</\1>` would be the wrong thing to do here, instead we would want `<year>.*?</year>`).

Initially you would probably create a class to hold information about a recognised token, for example:

```
public class Token
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    public string InnerText { get; private set; }

    public string this[string attributeName]
    {
        get
        {
            string val;
            _attributes.TryGetValue(attributeName, out val);
            return val;
        }
    }

    public Token(string innerText, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values)
    {
        InnerText = innerText;
        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            _attributes.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }

    public int GetInteger(string name, int defaultValue)
    {
        string val;
        int result;
        if (_attributes.TryGetValue(name, out val) && int.TryParse(val, out result))
            return result;
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Now we need to create the regex. For example, a regex to match your `year` element would look like:

```
<Year(?>\s*(?<aname>\w*?)\s*=\s*"(?<aval>[^"]*)"\s*)*>(?<itext>.*?)</Year>
```

So we can generalise this to:

```
<{0}\s*(?>(?<aname>\w*?)\s*=\s*"(?<aval>[^"]*)"\s*)*>(?<itext>.*?)</{0}>
<{0}\s*(?>(?<aname>\w*?)\s*=\s*"(?<aval>[^"]*)"\s*)*/>
```

Given those general tag regexes we can write the markup class:

```
public class MyMarkup
{
    // These are used to build up the regex.
    const string RegexInnerText = @"<{0}\s*(?>(?<aname>\w*?)\s*=\s*""(?<aval>[^""]*)""\s*)*>(?<itext>.*?)</{0}>";
    const string RegexNoInnerText = @"<{0}\s*(?>(?<aname>\w*?)\s*=\s*""(?<aval>[^""]*)""\s*)*/>";

    private static LinkedList<Tuple<Regex, MatchEvaluator>> _replacers = new LinkedList<Tuple<Regex, MatchEvaluator>>();

    static MyMarkup()
    {
        Register("year", false, tok =>
        {
            var count = tok.GetInteger("digits", 4);
            var yr = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
            if (yr.Length > count)
                yr = yr.Substring(yr.Length - count);
            return yr;
        });
    }

    private static void Register(string tagName, bool supportsInnerText, Func<Token, string> replacement)
    {
        var eval = CreateEvaluator(replacement);

        // Add the no inner text variant.
        _replacers.AddLast(Tuple.Create(CreateRegex(tagName, RegexNoInnerText), eval));
        // Add the inner text variant.
        if (supportsInnerText)
            _replacers.AddLast(Tuple.Create(CreateRegex(tagName, RegexInnerText), eval));
    }

    private static Regex CreateRegex(string tagName, string format)
    {
        return new Regex(string.Format(format, Regex.Escape(tagName)), RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }

    public static string Execute(string input)
    {
        foreach (var replacer in _replacers)
            input = replacer.Item1.Replace(input, replacer.Item2);
        return input;
    }

    private static MatchEvaluator CreateEvaluator(Func<Token, string> replacement)
    {
        return match =>
        {
            // Grab the groups/values.
            var aname = match.Groups["aname"];
            var aval = match.Groups["aval"];
            var itext = match.Groups["itext"].Value;

            // Turn aname and aval into a KeyValuePair.
            var attrs = Enumerable.Range(0, aname.Captures.Count)
                .Select(i => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(aname.Captures[i].Value, aval.Captures[i].Value));

            return replacement(new Token(itext, attrs));
        };
    }
}
```

It's all really rough work, but it should give you a good idea of what you should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

`string.Replace` is sufficient for the first requirement - no need for a RegEx.

```
string.Replace(myString, "<year />", @"<year offset=""2"" /">")
```

In order to extract the attribute value - you can `split` on `"`:

```
var val = @"<year offset=""2"" /">".Split('"')[1];
```

---

Update (following comments):

You can try using the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse and manipulate the text. It operates well on HTML fragments - well and mal-formed, though I am not sure how it would deal with custom tags (worth a shot). It *might* be overkill though.

Comment: I don't think he needs to substitute one syntax with another, but to process both of them (extracting param in second syntax if present) :)

Comment: Yeah, I need to extract the attributes value too

Comment: I will need to be adding more than one attribute to the tag aswell.

Comment: @codemonkey - Please note _all_ of your requirements in the question... We don't read minds.

Comment: I didn't think of adding that until I saw your solution which would only work with one attribute.